# iOS: Obtain the volume key events

Tags: ios

I have seen several applications can use the volume keys to switch between tasks, but I can not find the relevant information, such as: "Camera +" This application

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at [RBVolumeButtons](https://github.com/blladnar/RBVolumeButtons) to get you started.

The author has also written a [blog post](http://fredandrandall.com/blog/2011/11/18/taking-control-of-the-volume-buttons-on-ios-like-camera/) with some more information.